# Bootstrap width is overflowing and not fitting to form content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overflow

I have several forms on a webpage (utilizing Bootstrap 4) and all of them have some content overflow. I can't figure out how to fix it and make the width to fit the form content. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVn7A.png) is a screenshot of one of the simpler forms. [This is another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9JLa.png) of the other forms in case it helps. Below is some of my code.

page.html

```html
<div class="admin_section">
    <h3>Removals</h3>

    <div class="admin_section_content container">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="deleteName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Remove a Menu Item</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" name="remove_item_name" pattern="^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-' ]+$" maxlength="25"
                        class="form-control" id="deleteName" placeholder="Food Item Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="removeItem" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeItem" name="remove_item_button"
                        value="clicked">Remove Item</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <br><br>

        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="deleteReceipt" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Refund a Receipt</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" name="remove_receipt_number" pattern="^\d{10}$" minlength="10" maxlength="10"
                        class="form-control" id="deleteReceipt" placeholder="Receipt Number" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="removeReceipt" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeReceipt" name="remove_receipt_button"
                        value="clicked">Refund Receipt</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

general.css

```css
.admin_section{
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.admin_section_content{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

select{
    border-color: var(--bootstrap-grey);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

form{
    background-color: var(--form-grey);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
}

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi Yariel. Looking at your screenshots I cannot see where anything is overflowing? It all looks very tidy, aligned horizontally and vertically with placeholders in each form field looking very reasonable.

Comment: Hello! My concern is that it looks a bit long and empty for sections like "Removals" which only consist of a button and a simple form input.

Comment: I am a little unsure what you mean.  Do you mean reducing the width of the light grey containers or the input fields themselves? If you mean the grey containers you could perhaps house the entire `form-group` inside a `col`. Hopefully then you can specify the width of the col eg `col-2 col-3 col-4 etc`.

Comment: Yep, I mean the light grey containers. They give off a lot of extra space to the right. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the extra information Yariel. See what happens if you put the form inside a column.

````
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">

        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="deleteName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Remove a Menu Item</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" name="remove_item_name" pattern="^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ-' ]+$" maxlength="25"
                        class="form-control" id="deleteName" placeholder="Food Item Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="removeItem" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeItem" name="remove_item_button"
                        value="clicked">Remove Item</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

</div>

```
````